# Postgresql log rotation

Tags: postgresql, logs

In postgresql, I'm using the following configuration to maintain my weekly logs:

```
log_truncate_on_rotation = on
log_rotation_age = 1d
log_filename = 'postgresql-%a.log'
log_rotation_size = 0  #just rotate daily
```

This creates a log file with a name like 'postgresql-Mon.log' and when rotation occurs, it overrides the old file with the same name. This way I'm able to maintain a weekly log.

I now want to move this configuration to keeping the log for *just one day, instead of 7 days.* How do you suggest I tweak the config given above to achieve this? Do I only need to change the log_filename to `postgresql.log`? Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as (like you described) rotation replaces the file with the same name, you can find whichever name you like, without any daily changing bits.